# What App Service Database Controller should I use for Cordova?

Tags: cordova, azure, azure-web-app-service

I'm new to Azure - So far I've completed tutorials "Create an Apache Cordova app", "Add Authentication", "Add Push Notifications". Now I want to add a table to my App Service but can't find a good article. They all seem to be based on the old Mobile Services rather than the new App Service.

I read the article, "Work with the .NET backend server SDK for Azure Mobile Apps" and was left with more questions than answers. Now I'm not sure if TableController is the best controller for what I need based on all the other ones available.

What is the best article that will help me understand how to implement database/tables read, write, delete in an App Service and then consume it in a Cordova client?

Is there a list (matrix) of database controllers that will give a newbie an understanding of which one is best based on the client and circumstance?

Thanks for any help,
Mike

Comment: Tutorial recommendation questions are off-topic for StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for the client side i would recommend to use the [official client Cordova library for the Mobile Apps](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-cordova-how-to-use-client-library/).

As for the backend, you can:

1) Create Easy Tables connection (SQL Server of storage)

2) Create Easy API

3) Configure access to the API (GET, POST, etc) - with the auth key or without, etc
[image]
4) Invoke that API using client library

If you want to create a new table, you may want to initialize the object model for that and map for the table in the backend.

As for push notifications, you have two ways (both of them are configurable from the dashboard):

1) You may send the notification as a reaction on the API action invoked. For example, if there is an insert operation user invoked, the corresponding POST scripts is being executed, where you can do whatever you want - for example, to send the notification. It is the simplest way, but i can't say that it is very flexible.

2) Notification Hub (in the Settings of your web app, Push pane). NH is basically the mechanism to send notifications. It should be configured to use the notifications platform - if you use Windows, it is WNS, APNS for Apple, etc. Every platform has its own set of parameters you should configure. It is the connection that will allow your app to ask for send the notification - next, the cloud backend checks if your backend web app is connected with the notifications platform and if so asks the platform to send the push. That how it works (from 10000 meters) :-). NH is a powerful mechanism - it can works with tags (for example, if you want to send the push from your app to concrete users, you can subscribe them to some unique tag and then target them).

The first way is more client platform agnostic, the second is more flexible, but i am not sure if there is a out-of-the-box support for Cordova. You may start from that [plugin](https://github.com/sgrebnov/cordova-plugin-azure-notificationhub).

Comment: Thanks for the info on Easy Tables! I did give it a try and as its name implies its easy enough. However, I do want to implement push notifications. As that is a codeless solution my guess is that it doesn't allow for push notifications. Is that correct? If not, what is the best sql controller that can be implemented on the client and server in an API that also allows for push notifications?

Comment: @Mike as that question is too broad from my point of view i added that to the answer not the comment. Regarding controller - you do not need any SQL controllers to handle the notifications stuff. You should register the application for notifications and request to send them. And you should set up the backend - it is basically the process of copy-pasting security information from the corresponding notifications platform to the mobile app dashboard.